# NullPointerException can't find the error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dijkstra

Can't find the reason why I'm getting this NullPointException. It's pointing to 2 specific line.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Railroad.dijkstra(Railroad.java:52)
at Railroad.main(Railroad.java:36)
```

These are the 2 lines:

```
dijkstra(A);

for (Edge x : w.edges){
```

This is the whole code for convenience:

Posting the whole code for easier to understand where I'm coming from. Hopefully it'll help, thanks!

```
    Vertex[] vertices = { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M };
    dijkstra(A);
    for (Vertex v : vertices)
{
    System.out.println("Distance to " + v + ": " + v.shortestDist);
    List<Vertex> trip = cheapestTrip(v);
    System.out.println("Path: " + trip);
}
}

public static void dijkstra(Vertex s){
    s.shortestDist = 0;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> cityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    cityQueue.add(s);

    while(!cityQueue.isEmpty()){
        Vertex w = cityQueue.poll();
        for (Edge x : w.edges){
            Vertex v = x.city;
            int price = x.price;
            int priceOfTrip = w.shortestDist + price;
            if(priceOfTrip < v.shortestDist){   //relaxes the edge that it's on
                cityQueue.remove(v);
                v.shortestDist = priceOfTrip;
                v.prev = w;
                cityQueue.add(v);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you point the line Railroad.java:52 in your code?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie He did.

Comment: Please post the code for `Vertex`. I suspect that some `Vertex` object's `edges` field isn't getting initialized properly.

Comment: @chrylis Yes you are right, I was thinking about code from another part... The problem is probably from `PriorityQueue#poll()` as you said.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Deleted that answer because I didn't pay enough attention to the `while` clause. The OP is handling the queue correctly, but I think the problem is with `w.edges.iterator()`.

Comment: @chrylis Just posted the vertex code, I could even post the whole code if that's more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `NullPointerException` because the `edges` field on your `Vertex` object isn't getting properly initialized. It's generally best to use `private` fields and getters; this would have caused warnings about the potential problem.

Inside your `Vertex` class, you should initialize `edges`. Since you haven't posted the code, we don't know what type it is, but if it's a `Set`, for example, you would say:

```
Set<Edge> edges = Collections.emptySet(); // if you are going to replace edges
Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<>();        // if you are going to use edges.add()
```

**Edit:** `edges` is an array. The same principle applies; you aren't setting that `edges` variable anywhere, and so it defaults to `null`. A default that will prevent the immediate problem is

```
Edge[] edges = new Edge[0];
```

but you're better off refactoring to a collection type that will let you add an arbitrary number of edges, and better off still refactoring to enforce field encapsulation among your different classes.

**Edit 2:** The specific problem is with `K` (DC) and `M` (NY). You set the `edges` field on other cities, but not on those.

Comment: I just posted my entire code, maybe that'll make it clearer. I'm pretty sure I'm doing it correctly unless there's something I'm missing which I think I am.

Comment: LIFE SAVER, that was it! Thanks!! :)

Oh and the reason I didn't set an edge on M(NY) was because that was the last node/city, so it doesn't have one